Synthetic roof underlayment over asphalt felt
For my shed, I installed #30 asphalt felt on one half of the roof, and synthetic underlayment on the other half (didn’t buy enough felt to finish project in one day and no stores had it). For peace of mind, could I go over it all again with a synthetic underlayment, so it’s uniform, or could I actually cause myself issues? The felt/synthetic was installed correctly with 19” horizontal overlaps (parallel to eaves).

It's a shed, why redo work you already have done.
